# Unable to play mp4 stream using MediaPlayerElement in UWP

Tags: video, uwp, udp

I'm receiving a .mp4 stream over UDP and want to show the video in real time in a UWP app. I'm receiving the UDP data as an IInputStream and which I then convert to an IRandomAccessStream and create a MediaSource from the IRandomAccessStream, and set the MediaSource as the source for a MediaPlayerElement.

`IRandomAccessStream stream = iinputstream.AsStreamForRead().AsRandomAccessStream();`

`MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, "video/mp4");`

`mediaPlayerElement.Source = mediaSource;`

After running the application, MediaPlayerElement always shows the error "Unsupported Video Type or Invalid File Path". I have tried playing a local mp4 file using similar setup and it works without any issues, but if I send the same file over UDP, MediaPlayerElement does not play it and shows the same error as above. Also,  I have already checked the data coming over UDP is correct as I wrote this data to a file, which the MediaPlayerElement was able to play successfully.

Is there something I'm missing in the code or doing incorrectly?

P.S.  While looking for a solution, I came across MediaStreamSource and decided to give it try and was able to play a local file with no issues. Changing the setup to play using the UDP stream data, MediaStreamSource kept pausing after requesting a single sample and thus never played the video.

Comment: You need a stream that contains the complete MP4 file instead of an incoming stream if you want to use `MediaSource.CreateFromStream()`. That's why you get the error saying `Unsupported Video Type or Invalid File Path`.  For your scenario, maybe you could check [Adaptive streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming).

Comment: Thanks for replying @RoyLi-MSFT. I can't use adaptive streaming as I'm trying to live stream video recorded from a capture device with latency less than 100ms. If MediaSource won't be able to play the incoming stream, any idea what could help?

Comment: what about MediaSource.CreateFromUri?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I've tried CreateFromUri before and that didn't work as well.

Comment: Could you please share an [mcve] on Github or OneDrive with us? We could take a look at how the code is working.

Comment: Another thing is that, could you please try the test MP4 file content - [sample MP4 files](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mp4-files/). I recognize you have tested your content and that I only want to verify if the behavior is happening for multiple pieces of content